# Point Keeps Returning to Same Spot in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Every now and then Emacs develops this annoying behaviour of remembering a position in a buffer. Whenever I leave the buffer and return the point automatically moves back to the same position.

I probably hit some random command without being aware of it, but does anyone know what this is and how I can stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I think saveplace is useful in such case.
you add following S-exp in your configuration file.

```
(load "saveplace")
(setq-default save-place t)
```

See Also

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SavePlace

Comment: It's not so much that I want this functionality, but that it's happening and I don't want it.